# Load view on double-click of row - have bindings working, and event being fired on click, but how do I actually get the view to pop up?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, view, event-handling, telerik

I have a view in Silverlight which contains a `telerik:RadGridView` with a number of columns.

I have it wired up so that when the user double-clicks on one of these columns, an event is fired. However, I don't know what to put in the event handler.

```
        private void RowClicked()
        {
          //What goes here?
        }
```

All I wish to do is load a popup view over my current view, with a close button so that the user can return to the previous view. A simple idea that is surely done a billion times everywhere, but I cannot figure it out or find examples of this anywhere.

Can anyone help?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a previous view as input parameter to "RowClicked()" method. You will have a reference on previous view in current method. You can use it via Commands (bind a command and a command parameter to some action/event).

I have an one more idea (if you have a lot of views): you can create a navigation service. It is an interface, which contains events and methods. You should use events for navigation and methods - for sending needed data. Everyone of view should implement this interface. Needed event will be raised under view via some action (for example: button click). As for events: you can create a custom event handler, there you will set a sender instance and needed parameters. You should create a Navigation manager, there you should create a property for selected view and subscribe on everyone event. If user want navigate to another view, he will do some action and system will raise an event. You can create a custom container for created views. This container you can use for getting created instance of needed view. As you know, creating a new instance is heavy for system: need a some time and system resources. Will be easy to get a created instance of view instead a create a new. For setting default data or refreshing a binding you can user a custom method, contractor for which will be added to navigation interface.

It is a simple idea, which I used in one project. As for others samples: You can find another navigation frameworks and custom classes in internet. But, process of creating an own system will give you a level up in your work experience.

Comment: as for second using views, which needed everytime: you can add all this to App resources and write a own helper, which will get the needed one.